# Генерация сочетаний

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

Необходимо построить сочетания всех возможных размеров так, чтобы элементы в сочетаниях не совпадали (1,2,3; 1,3,2; 2,1,3; 2,3,1; 3,1,2; 3,2,1 - одни и те же сочетания)

Например, даны числа: 1,2,3,4

Ответ:

1
2
3
4

12
13
14
23
24
34

123
124
134

1234

Можно и псевдокод.

Comment: вот как в Питоне можно [power set сгенерировать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27888361/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли еще 234 и пустое сочетание :)

Берем число, каждому биту которого соответствует один элемент вашего множества, и проходим все числа в цикле - от 00..00 до 11..11. Все. Каждое число - это одно "сочетание" (вообще-то это **генерация всех подмножеств данного множества**), которое строим, выбирая элементы, соответствующие единичным битам...

Например, ваше 1234 - соответственно, 4-битное число...

```
0000   пустое множество
0001   1
0010   2
0011   12
0100   3
....
1110   432
1111   4321
```

Comment: спасибо, оказывается, это намного проще, чем я думал)

Comment: красивый алгоритм :)